# How to query on Elasticsearch a value on a root field and a range on a nested array field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a `clients` index with the following structure:

```json
{
  client_id: uuid,
  name.keyword: keyword,
  events: [
    { created_at: date, id: uuid},
    { created_at: date, id: uuid}
  ]
}
```

There are multiple `events` under each client record.

How can I query this index to get records with `client_id = 123` and `events.created_at` in the range between "2021-01-01" and "2022-01-01".

I need to only include clients with at least one event that matches the range. I seem to always get all the records in response, because when there are multiple events, one of them will always match one of the range checks.

---

*UPDATE 7. Jun 2023:* Here's what I tried so far:

**Lots of variations of `nested` searches**

```json
GET /clients/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "events.created_at": {
                "gte": "2023-05-21T00:00:00Z",
                "lte": "2023-06-21T00:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": "ACME Inc."
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This returns NO hits.

**Same as above but without the root level `name.keyword` filter**

```json
GET /clients/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "events.created_at": {
                "gte": "2023-05-21T00:00:00Z",
                "lte": "2023-06-21T00:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This returns too many hits. The date filter does "something" but the result is 10x more hits than expected.

**No `nested`/`path`, let's see…**

```json
GET /clients/_search
{  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "name.keyword": "ACME Inc."
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "events.created_at": {
              "gte": "2023-01-01T00:00:00.000+01:00",
              "lt": "2023-01-02T00:00:00.000+01:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [],
      "must_not": []
    }
  }
}
```

This returns NO hits.

Answer (score 1):

With help from @val I put together this query that does the job:

```json
GET /clients/_search
{
  "_source": ["name.keyword","events.created_at"], 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [],
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name.keyword": "ACME Inc."
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "events",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "events.created_at": {
                  "gte": "2021-06-20T00:00:00Z",
                  "lte": "2021-09-20T00:00:00Z"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Way to go Gabriel, great job!